# Are contract views typechecked when only the main contract code is called?

Tags: michelson, gas, on-chain-views

I have been contemplating replacing off-chain views entirely with on-chain views in my contracts since the former leads to unnecessary work of having an otherwise redundant metadata big-map with a Michelson storage view. However, my only concern is large views bumping up the gas consumption on calling normal entrypoints.

I see an issue on Gitlab (https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/issues/2237) but related MRs in the comments don't seem to have been merged.

PS: I have not considered the extra one-time origination cost due to the increase in the size of the contract file to be deployed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I think that currently, all the code and views are type-checked.

A workaround is to declare views are global constants. But there is no support for this in high-level SC languages for the moment I think.